# Parsing Resharper code analysis xml on team build

Tags: resharper, tfsbuild

I'm using this new Resharper [Command line tool](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+InspectCode) in my Team build, to analyze code issues.
This works fine, it generates an XML file with all the code issues.

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to parse the XML. For every Issue I want to write a build warning or build error.

The xml looks like this:

```
<Report ToolsVersion="8.0">
   <IssueTypes>...</IssueTypes>
   <Project Name="FooBar">
       <Issue TypeId="FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Local" File="Builder.cs" Offset="266-277" Line="10" Message="Field can be made readonly" />
...
   </Project>
</Report>
```

Is their any xml parser available that I can plug into my build process template? Or do I need to make my own console application that parses the xml?

Comment: Have you considered sending your custom activity to the [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com) project? I think we will start integrating resharper in the build process in the very near future and it would be nice to have this centralized and thoroughly tested like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if an XML parser exists or one can be integrated into a workflow, but a possibility is to create a custom build activity and hook that into your build process.

The activity could then read the XML file containing the issues and fill an `IEnumerable<string>`. (or an object, I believe you should be able to create an object and access the properties from within the workflow.) In your workflow you can then capture the output enumerable, loop over it and write build errors or warnings (or both) to your build output.

Ewald Hofman has an excellent blog post on how to [create your own activity](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx), it's actually quite easy and gives you a lot of control over the actual operation.

Answer (score -1):

TeamCity have bundled ReSharper runner (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Inspections+%28.NET%29). You don't have run runner as standalone app. Errors from bundled runner are treated as build errors.

Comment: Please, follow and vote for this issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-395854 to get implemented inspectcode as MSBuild task.